# Can a local/on premises domain Trust Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am not sure this is possible, but can Azure AD be trusted by a local on-premises domain?

I can see plenty of information on extending the local domain into Azure, but my requirement is more of less the reverse of this.

Ideally I would like the local domain to trust Azure AD, but as an alternative 
could Azure AD DS be used to extend Azure AD into an Azure AD DS domain and then have a two way trust with the local domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure this is possible, but can Azure AD be trusted by a local
>   on-premises domain?

As I know, there is no way to make Azure AD be trusted by a local on-premise domain.

[Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis) is used for authentication for Internet-based services such as Office 365 and Azure, as well as much more, including Facebook and thousands of other services that are already federated with Azure AD (which mean they trust Azure AD without you having to do anything other than enable that application or service to be used by your users).

Your on-premises Active Directory can be synced to Azure AD by using Azure AD Connect (including password sync) and federation. This allows users on their corporate assets to log on with their AD account and when they access Internet services, such as Office 365, authentication with Azure AD just happens seamlessly via the federation, allowing access to all the different services that Azure AD is federated with.

[Azure AD Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview) provides managed domain services such as domain join, group policy, LDAP, Kerberos/NTLM authentication that are fully compatible with Windows Server Active Directory. You can consume these domain services without the need for you to deploy, manage, and patch domain controllers in the cloud. Azure AD Domain Services integrates with your existing Azure AD tenant, thus making it possible for users to log in using their corporate credentials.